# How to write a code for agent side response for give request in pysnmp for example a get-request and what are the required prerequisite

Tags: pysnmp

I am trying to code a agent which can response to the request from the manager. i am unable to know from where to start and what are the steps to be followed

I am using ubuntu-18.04.2 LTS and i want to know the commands required to do my job

Example code for agent is needed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Reading this will aid you to get help you need.

Comment: There are tons of examples but a more recent one is https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/blob/v6.0.5/tests/agent_context.py#L16